# How to add a newline inside \overset?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, line-breaking, overset

Example:

```
$abc \overset{a=1,b=2,c=3}{=} c!$
```

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to figure out how to add newlines instead of commas between `a=1` and `b=2` and `b=2` and `c=3`.

Comment: Note that in general this sort of writing is frowned upon in typeset text. It is better to write the `a=1,b=2,c=3` in the text before or after.

Comment: Mainly because it looks bad. It belongs on a blackboard or when writing by hand on a piece of paper. Also note that given how you here write it as text mode math (`$...$`), a construction like this will disturb the line spacing and look even worse. You will not see this type of writing in any processionally handled text book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$abc \overset{\scriptsize\begin{array}{c}a=1\\b=2\\c=3\end{array}}{=} c!$
```

[image]

**Edit:** Another option that wasn't mentioned by others, if you want a more compact form, is to use `\substack`:

```
$abc \overset{\substack{a=1\\b=2\\c=3}}{=} c!$
```

[image]

Comment: `\scriptsize` is invalied in math-mode, you need `\scriptstyle`. Might be easier to just use `subarray` instead of `array`, then `\scriptstyle` is not needed.

Comment: With `\smash[t]{\mathstrut}` in the last row of `\substack` you get a small vertical gap.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the enviroment `smallmatrix`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[abc \overset{\begin{smallmatrix} a=1\\b=2\\c=3 \end{smallmatrix}}{=} c!\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the suggestion of the user **@egreg**: *With \smash[t]{\mathstrut} in the last row of \substack you get a small vertical gap*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[abc \overset{\begin{smallmatrix} a=1\\b=2\\\smash[t]{\mathstrut} c=3 \end{smallmatrix}}{=} c!\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using `\begin{subarray}` instead of `\begin{array}`:

```
$abc \overset{\begin{subarray}{c}a=1\\b=2\\c=3\end{subarray}}{=} c!$
```

[image: screenshot]